# Object has been deleted or invalidated

Tags: swift, realm

This problem has been listed down a lot but I can't see the one that fits my scenario. I have a function to add and remove music to/from favorite. I can add it at first and also can remove it. But after I add it again. Boom!!! Please anyone help me. Thank you!

Error Thrown below:

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason: 'Adding a deleted or invalidated object to a Realm is not permitted'

Please help me review code below:

```
func addMusicToFavorite(music: Music) {
    let realm = try! Realm()

    try! realm.write {
        realm.add(music)
    }

}

func removeMusicFromFavorite(music: Music) {
    //Tips: '\(musics.mId)' : put quote ' ' like this means String, if not it will treat it as Int
    let realm = try! Realm()
    let tmpMusic = realm.objects(Music.self).filter("_mId == '\(music.mId)'")
    try! realm.write {
        print("remove \(music.mId)")
        realm.delete(tmpMusic)
    }
}
```

My Music Model:

```
class Music: Object {

private dynamic var _mId: String!
private dynamic var _mTitle: String!
private dynamic var _mArtist: String!
private dynamic var _mThumbnail: String!
private dynamic var _mAlbumImg: String!
private dynamic var _mPath: String!
private dynamic var _mNumOfView: String!
private dynamic var _mDuration: String!

var mId: String {
    return _mId
}

var mTitle: String {
    return _mTitle
}

var mArtist: String {
    return _mArtist
}

var mAlbumImg: String {
    return _mAlbumImg
}

var mThumbnail: String {
    return _mThumbnail
}

var mPath: String {
    return _mPath
}

var mNumOfView: String {
    return _mNumOfView
}

var mDuration: String {
    return _mDuration
}

required init() {
    super.init()
}

required init(realm: RLMRealm, schema: RLMObjectSchema) {
    super.init(realm: realm, schema: schema)
```

//        fatalError("init(realm:schema:) has not been implemented")
    }

```
required init(value: AnyObject, schema: RLMSchema) {
    super.init(value: value, schema: schema)
```

//        fatalError("init(value:schema:) has not been implemented")
    }

```
override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
    return "_mId"
}


convenience init(dict: Dictionary<String, AnyObject>) {
    self.init()

    if let id = dict["id"] as? String {
        self._mId = id
    }

    if let titleAndArtist = dict["music_title"] as? String {
        let tmp = Utils.instance.splitStringsWithCharacter(titleAndArtist)
        self._mTitle = tmp.title
        self._mArtist = tmp.artist            
    }

    if let thumbnail = dict["image_thumb"] as? String {
        self._mThumbnail = thumbnail
    }

    if let albumImg = dict["image_album"] as? String {
        self._mAlbumImg = albumImg
    }

    if let path = dict["music_path"] as? String {
        self._mPath = path
    }

    if let numOfView = dict["music_view"] as? String {
        self._mNumOfView = numOfView
    }

    if let duration = dict["music_duration"] as? String {
        self._mDuration = duration
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Could you show the model for the `Music` object?

Comment: Hi xoudini, Thank you for your comment, Please check my edited question which added the model of Music...Thanks!

Comment: Can you evaluate on "Boom!!!"? ;) Does Realm throw an error, does the app get terminated, ...?

Comment: Hi HAS, haha...sounds funny...the app is terminated and throw realm exception with the reason: Object has been invalidated or deleted...Just like this...Sorry for unclear question, I'm gonna edit my question soon...Thank you...:)

Comment: Please check my edited question for thrown errors. @HAS

Comment: Are you trying to add the exact same object you just deleted? You should create a new object to add and not try to re-add the deleted one if that's the case

Comment: Try to make the realm a property and use it in both cases.

Comment: Hi Volkan, yes i try to re-add the deleted object, simply having a button which trigger add/remove, click one add, click again will remove, sth like that... I will follow your way, m a bit newbie to realm...so need some time to figure it out...:) but Thank you Volkan...:)

Comment: Hi Has, first i declare realm property as global, and then i separate it like now...but problem is not solved...Thank you, Have you got any suggestion? @HAS

Comment: Dear Volkan, Follow your ways and now it's solved. Thank you very much, genius... :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just for the records as the answer is buried a bit in all the comments: You can't re-`add` the *same object instance* once you delete it from a Realm.

`realm.add` persists the given object. The properties of such objects are managed after this call in the database directly on disk instead of just in plain memory.

But if you keep the unmanaged object and create a copy in the Realm by using `realm.create(object)` instead, you can repeat that, even after deleting objects created in such way.